# if condition - jquery response

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using jquery-ajax to send data to a php. Upon success or failure the php sends back a response. so far everything works fine. Now my questions is how do I use an if statement in jquery to do some action using the response?

```
$.post("php/send.php",
     { 
       email:$( '#email' ).val(),
       name:$( '#name' ).val()
     },
     function(response) {
       //alert(response) 
       if (response == "errorA") {
          //do A...
       } else if (response == "errorB") {
          //do B...
       } else {
          //do C...
       }
   )};
```

My if statement does not work. Even the response from the php is "errorA" or "errorB" it will //do A. How do I fix this?

Comment: What is the **exact** content of the response being sent by the server?

Comment: Use `console.log()` to get what is response.

Comment: try using three if's instead of if()...else if()

Comment: @esqew: `errorA`, `errorB`.

Comment: @Satpal: I'm getting the correct response but I can not use it in the IF statement. That's my problem.

Comment: @Anonymous.X: Why is that? How can that solve the problem? what about the final ELSE then?

Comment: just try it it works

Comment: Try `if (response.trim() == "errorA")`

Comment: @Anonymous.X: Assuming 2 if statements is going to work, what about the final ELSE statement? What will be the condition of it?

Comment: like i said use 3 if statements so there is no question of an else stament

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the response you are getting back is a comma separated string and JavaScript is treating it as an array.

Try below

```
if(response.indexOf("errorA")==0) {

}
else if(response.indexOf("errorB")==0) {

}
```

Comment: Why won't this respond? `if (!(response.indexOf("errorA") >= 0))`

Comment: What are you trying to acheive

Comment: thanks. I want to use the response to output an custom error message. This worked `if (response.trim() == "errorA") {`. But I'm not sure why you suggested this `if(response.indexOf("errorA")==0)` instead.

Comment: That is another solution. You can try both and pick the one that is working for you.